# psycopg2 cursor.copy_from() loading duplicates?

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

Using psycopg2 package in Python to load data from a CSV file to a table in Postgres. This CSV file gets regenerated every hour, and there may be duplicates in the file when compared to a file from another time. Some example code would look like this:

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(user='postgres',password='password',database='postgres')
cur = conn.cursor()

file = open('test.csv','r')
cur.copy_from(file,'table',sep=',')
conn.commit()
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

I'm pretty certain this method does not account for duplicates, is there another method that would account for duplicates directly, or would it be better off to save the CSV to a temp table and use cur.execute() as a query to insert into the final table?

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL v12 has a `WHERE` clause for `COPY ... FROM`, but you cannot use subqueries there.

So the only option is to load to a temporary table and then use `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT` to upsert the data.